# Is mov esp, ebp really necessary?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Taken into consideration that the stack grows downwards (lower-address) and assuming intel syntax.

With the following snippet:

```
main:

    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi

   ; ... do stuff

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp    ; <- necessary? i.e. can be omitted?
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I understand that before entering the function the current stack pointer is saved into the base pointer (=stack frame), but then from the instructions I find `mov esp, ebp` redundant; by popping the 3 registers **and** then the **into** the base pointer aren't you incrementing the stack pointer (higher address) and thus, at the same time, **restoring** the stack pointer?

Comment: It's not necessary if the value has already been restored as in your example.

Comment: It doesn't seem needed here, but it's needed in general if you decreased `esp` to make room for local variables.

Comment: @interjay can you point to an example? also I would accept it as an answer

Comment: I can only imagine `push` instructions after the `push ebp` and before `mov ebp, esp` (but not sure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you gave, the `mov esp, ebp` isn't necessary because the original value of `esp` is restored after the `pop` instructions and is already be equal to `ebp`.

But in general, this instruction may be needed if `esp` was decreased to make room for local variables. For example:

```
some_function:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 256      ; allocate 256 bytes for local variables

    ;  ... function body

    mov esp, ebp      ; restore esp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

These are the standard ["function prologue" and "function epilogue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) used in x86 code.

Comment: Compilers *do* leave it out in cases where it's redundant (and they're not omitting the frame-pointer entirely).  They just use `pop ebp` instead of `leave` (gcc) or `mov`/`pop` (clang) if they haven't moved ESP/RSP away from the saved EBP/RBP.  So the OP's code isn't what you'd see in real compiler output, only in boilerplate tutorials.